# Using output of command in further commands

Tags: shell-script, ubuntu

I am new to Linux and I need help to write script as following.

1. Running command to get output which is the ID#,

   ```bsh
   docker exec -it scalelite-api bin/rake servers:add[https://bbb1.test.com/bigbluebutton/api,XYZ1234]
   ```

   This will return ID#
2. Then I want to insert the output ID# into another line in the script.

   ```bsh
   docker exec -it scalelite-api bin/rake servers:enable[ID#]
   ```

Comment: Please take the [Tour](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn about how these sites generally work. Please see the Questions -section in the [Help](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help) to learn how to ask a good one. Please edit your question and add 1) the script you're currently using 2) what exactly is your expected results and 3) what exactly is the result you get. Please use the `{}` curly brackets around code, output etc. You will get help in fixing a non-working script, but nobody will write one for you. [From Review](https://unix.stackexchange.com/review/first-questions/390215)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming XYZ1234 is not a real value:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# myscript.sh

# ${1} denotes the first argument of the shell script
export ID=$(docker exec -it scalelite-api bin/rake "servers:add[https://bbb1.test.com/bigbluebutton/api,${1}]")
# Puts the value of the command output into environment variable "ID"

echo "$ID"
# Outputs the value of environment variable ID
```

```
$ chmod +x myscript.sh
$ ./myscript.sh "XYZ1234"
```

Of course, you can later add checking if the docker command failed, etc.

Comment: You seem to miss the point of the question: They need to use the ID in another call to `docker`.  It is also unclear why you need to `export` the ID and why you don't quote the string containing `$1`.  If they just needed to output the ID, then storing it in an intermediate variable would not be necessary.

Comment: @they Oh, sorry. I didn't understand at first that the "another line" was the line at the bottom. Apologies. `echo` here was just an example